# remove img tag of a TD element and simultaneously change the bgcolor tag value for a style

Tags: jquery, html, replace, tags

I have the following code in several pages like this.

```
<td bgcolor="#017842" height="4"><img src="images/pix.gif" border="0" width="1" height="1" /></td>
```

and will replace

```
<td height="4" style="line-height: 4px; background-color:#017842;"></td>
```

actually seeing it differently, I need that for every img tag with the value of the IMG SRC value is = 'images/pix.gif' remove the parent element, but before adding to parent element's style property line-height type ..

i tried with the solution posted here
[Using jQuery each to replace image source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242258/using-jquery-each-to-replace-image-source)

but i unable to resolve...

Not if you understand well, I hope I explained correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the first code snippet correct? `src` attribute on `td`?

Comment: remove the `bgcolor`  and toggle a class on the TD instead of inline style, easier to change back

Comment: show us the code you are trying to make work, you learn more from enhancing that code, and this site isn't meant for people to build code for you

Comment: Sidharth, your are correct, left img tag...i will edit

Comment: charlietfl, since this code is often valued, different colors or styles, I have to fix this problem by adding some jQuery code block to replace it in about 300 individual pages. if I put this code refactoring jquery, could save a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('td img').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('src') == 'images/pix.gif';
}).parent().css({'line-hight' : '4px', 'background-color' : '#017842'}).removeAttr('bgcolor').find('img').remove();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LJMBu/1/).

Comment: i tried your code and making some modification in order to make more visible the changes

I tried your code, but the image still there.
http://jsfiddle.net/yN55x/1/

Comment: Two points: *first* a `td` element is only valid if it's a child of a `tr` element (which in turn requires a `tbody`, `tfoot`, `thead` or, at least, a `table` element to be present as a parent of that `tr`). *Second* jQuery doesn't work on JS Fiddle *unless* you select `jQuery` from the drop-down menu on the left.

Comment: Oh!.. my bad!!...your are right David, Thanks and apologize for non-review-quick-bad-response from me...

Comment: Only one more question....how would that be set to the value of the new style "background-color" with the value of the label "bgcolor". Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

if you defined  id then it is simple;

```
$("#tdImg").empty();
```

Another with scenario - Show():

```
$("#tableId tr").each(function () {
            $(this).find("img").each(function () {
                $(this).show();
            });
        });
```

Scenario with hide():

```
$("#tableId tr").each(function () {      
            $(this).find("img").each(function () {                
                $(this).hide();
            });
    });
```

Also we can use remove() if need to remove the image using $(this).remove()